# Expression as function parameter for property and object type

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, .net-core

I require a function which takes as parameter the following things:

- The type of the object
- Name of a specific property of the object

Currently I do it in a rather inconvenient and long way:

```
public static void Add<TEntity, TProperty>(TEntity e, Expression<Func<TProperty>> expression)
{
     var type = typeof(TEntity);
     var propertyName = ((MemberExpression) expression.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

Which results in a function call like this: `Add(Foo, () => Foo.Bar);`

However with that solution I have a couple problems:

- It gets really long when I have a object like this: `Add(Foo.Bar.Element.Type, () => Foo.Bar.Element.Type.Name)` and looks quite ugly.
- It isn't ensured that `propertyName` is a property of the object's type.

  - I actually don't do anything really with `e` so it's not used.

Is there a better solution to this?

Comment: Could you be more specific with regard to what you want the function to do. Right now the sample doesn't do anything so it's difficult to know what you're looking for.

Comment: Having `Foo.Bar.Element.Type` is not problem of your function, but problem of your design. Following "Law of Demeter" when design classes will possible prevent this kind of problems, unless `Foo.Bar.Element.Type` is just hierarchy of data objects without behaviour

Comment: They're just data objects connected with each other and with no behavior.

Comment: @JSteward I basically want to access a specific Attribute of that property to do something with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve the first problem by adding a parameter to the lambda:

```
public static void Add<TEntity, TProperty>(TEntity e, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> expression)

Add(Foo.Bar.Element.Type, x => x.Name)
```

Comment: Solves both doesn't it?

Comment: `public static void Add<TEntity, TProperty>(this TEntity unused, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> exp)` should be nicer to use: `Foo.Bar.Element.Type.Add(x => x.Name)`

Comment: @SteveHarris: It doesn't prevent `x => UnrelatedObject.Foo`

Comment: As @SLaks said, it doesn't prevent the ` x=> UnrelatedObject.Foo` problem, but it's already a bit nicer, thanks for that!